# error: missing @end error: expected identifier or

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know that there are similar questions, but I still can not resolve it.

```
   error: missing @end [1]
    error: expected identifier or '(' [1]
    error: expected a type [1]
```

(get it in a header file)

I replaced this file with the new empty file with the same name - still get this error?

```
#import "Storage.h"

@implementation Storage

@end


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Storage : NSObject


@end
```

Comment: Show us the header file you mentioned (and other code, if neccessary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **PREVIOUS** header file is likely incomplete. There is a missing @end in a class interface. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-SW1

Comment: you was right, I had missing @tag in the other class, but f-g xcode debugger pointed it out to different class.

Comment: It's reporting the error where it first encounters unexpected input. In this case, it happens to be in the next header. Best to interpret "missing @end" as "Gee, I really think I was supposed to have seen an @end before this point."

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the .m file instead of the .h?

Like this, *obviously wrong, but can easily happen with autocompletion*

```
#import "myHeader.m"
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but a guess. Ask this as a comment to the question.